# Tools for UI Testing with integrated service

Tags: performance, jquery-ui, user-interface

What are the tools available for UI independent and integrated testing with Services & UI Performance testing ?

- Browser specific Tools
- Performance Specific Tools

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of testing frameworks out there. You may want to look at these:

1. [QUnit](http://qunitjs.com/) - JavaScript unit testing framework.
2. [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/download/) - Very good for cross-browser interaction testing